# Spring - NoSuchMethodException when calling a RestService

Tags: spring

I have this simple Mapping that should return me a List objects

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class ServerRESTController {

    @Autowired ServerService serverService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/server/{idServer}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Server> getFloorLatUpdate(@PathVariable int idServer){

        Server server = serverService.findById(idServer);

        return new ResponseEntity<Server>(server, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/server/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Server>> listAllServers(){

        List<Server> servers = serverService.findAllServers(-1);

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Server>>(servers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

}
```

Server.class is a model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "server")
public class Server implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int serverId;
    private Piano piano;
    private String nomeServer;
    private String serverIp;
    private String descrizione;
    private boolean online;
    private Set<Interruttore> interruttori;
    private String firmwareVersion;

    public Server(){

    }

    public Server(int serverId, Piano piano, String nomeServer, String serverIp, String descrizione, boolean online,
            Set<Interruttore> interruttori, String firmwareVersion){
        this.serverId = serverId;
        this.piano = piano;
        this.nomeServer = nomeServer;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
        this.online = online;
        this.interruttori = interruttori;
        this.setFirmwareVersion(firmwareVersion);
    }


    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_server", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    public int getServerId() {
        return serverId;
    }
    public void setServerId(int serverId) {
        this.serverId = serverId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_piano")
    public Piano getPiano() {
        return piano;
    }
    public void setPiano(Piano piano) {
        this.piano = piano;
    }

    @Column(name="nome_server")
    public String getNomeServer() {
        return nomeServer;
    }
    public void setNomeServer(String nomeServer) {
        this.nomeServer = nomeServer;
    }

    @Column(name="server_ip")
    public String getServerIp() {
        return serverIp;
    }
    public void setServerIp(String serverIp) {
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
    }

    @Column(name="descrizione")
    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }
    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    @Column(name="online")
    public boolean isOnline() {
        return online;
    }

    public void setOnline(boolean online) {
        this.online = online;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "server")
    public Set<Interruttore> getInterruttori() {
        return interruttori;
    }

    public void setInterruttori(Set<Interruttore> interruttori) {
        this.interruttori = interruttori;
    }

    @Column(name = "firmware_version")
    public String getFirmwareVersion() {
        return firmwareVersion;
    }

    public void setFirmwareVersion(String firmwareVersion) {
        this.firmwareVersion = firmwareVersion;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((descrizione == null) ? 0 : descrizione.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nomeServer == null) ? 0 : nomeServer.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (online ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((piano == null) ? 0 : piano.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + serverId;
        result = prime * result + ((serverIp == null) ? 0 : serverIp.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Server other = (Server) obj;
        if (descrizione == null) {
            if (other.descrizione != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!descrizione.equals(other.descrizione))
            return false;
        if (nomeServer == null) {
            if (other.nomeServer != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nomeServer.equals(other.nomeServer))
            return false;
        if (online != other.online)
            return false;
        if (piano == null) {
            if (other.piano != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!piano.equals(other.piano))
            return false;
        if (serverId != other.serverId)
            return false;
        if (serverIp == null) {
            if (other.serverIp != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!serverIp.equals(other.serverIp))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

When trying to call for the service i'm getting:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method [listAllServers] was discovered in the .class file but cannot be resolved in the class object
```

cause by

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: it.besmart.restcontroller.ServerRESTController.listAllServers()
```

I cannot understand why this happens, I have always used ResponseEntity in this way... maybe it's for the List?

Comment: How are you running/building your project? maven? which maven plugin? what IDE are you using? I don't think, it's because of the List<Server>

Comment: I'm using maven with maven compie plugin. My IDE is eclipse but i build via command line. My other rest controllers work normally...

Comment: are you using aspectJ ?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the whole code so we can find out.

This usually comes when the method is invoked at the wrong place or when there is a mismatch in build and runtime environments or when you miss arguments in a constructor and so on.

Also, you may want to check the files in the classpath. There may be a mismatch between compile time and actual runtime environments for some reason. For example, you say that you build it using command line. So, there may be some discrepancy there, no harm in checking.

Finally, you can check for spelling mistakes - I know that sounds strange, but case sensitivity is important.

Comment: edited the first question to add the whole controller and the model